# I am unable to crate app , getting error in npm

Tags: npm, compiler-errors, operating-system

Installing packages...non WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.3: Legacy versions of mkdrip are no longer supported. Please update to mkdrip 1.x. (Note that API surface has changed to use promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see http://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN optional SKIPPINGOPTION DEPENDENCY:fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}(current: {"os":"win32":"arch":"×64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:fsevents@1.2.7(node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...2","koala":"0.1.2","1'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
× Package install failed, see above.
The schematic workflow failed. See above.

Comment: You need more information about what you were doing when you received these errors. You may have damaged files, try deleting the node_modules folder, clearing the npm cache, and installing everything again.

Answer (score -1):

The critical part of this error that needed reading

```
unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}(current: {"os":"win32":"arch":"×64"})
```

This means it needs to run on OSX, not Windows.